# Input string into url - using html form and javascript

Tags: javascript, string, forms, input

```
<p><input name="form[ip]" id="ip" class="ip" type="text" value="Enter IP here" />
</p>            
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p> ​   


var currentPageURL = "http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=12.215.42.19&position=true";
var ip = getMeasurementsFromUrl(currentPageURL)

alert(ip);

function getMeasurementsFromUrl(ip)
{

var ipMeasurmentString = ip.substring(ip.lastIndexOf('ip=')+3);

ipMeasurmentString =ipMeasurmentString.replace("&position=true",""); 
ipMeasurmentString =ipMeasurmentString.replace(",","."); 
ipMeasurmentString =ipMeasurmentString.replace("/","."); 
ipMeasurmentString =ipMeasurmentString.replace("-",".");
ipMeasurmentString =ipMeasurmentString.replace(",","."); 
ipMeasurmentString =ipMeasurmentString.replace("/","."); 
ipMeasurmentString =ipMeasurmentString.replace("-",".");
ipMeasurmentString =
return ipMeasurmentString;
}
```

​
I am trying to edit the webaddress so it reads the inputted ip, so far i have got it to read the ip currently in the address and have a form to input the ip.

Also if anyone has any tips on how to maker the form more ip formatted would be helpful.

http://jsfiddle.net/mqWGm/8/

Comment: is the currentPageURL string fixed? or does it change?

Comment: i'm trying to get it so the inputted ip can be put into the currentPageURL and then the .php will be outputed in the html.

Comment: Hi Greezer, it changes to the ip from the inputform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ip adres does not change you could use:

```
element = document.getElementById("ip");
var newstring = ipMeasurmentString.replace("ip=12.215.42.19&",element.value);
```

if it change you could try:

```
var part = str.split("ip=");
var newstring = part[0] + "ip=" + element.value + "&position=true"; //part[0] = text before the ip=
```